# android Custom Adapter append one item only

Tags: java, android, listview

this my java code

```
public class profile extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    String[] web = profile.this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_labels);


    Integer[] imageId = {
            R.drawable.ic_home,
            R.drawable.ic_tv,
            R.drawable.ic_ticket,
            R.drawable.ic_offers,
            R.drawable.ic_earning,
            R.drawable.ic_usemoney,
            R.drawable.ic_ranking,
            R.drawable.ic_faq,
            R.drawable.ic_symbol21,


    };



    profile.CustomList adapter1 = new
            profile.CustomList(profile.this, web, imageId);
    ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
    list.setAdapter(adapter1);

}
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] web;
    private final Integer[] imageId;
    public CustomList(Activity context,
                      String[] web, Integer[] imageId) {
        super(context, R.layout.nav_drawer_row, web);
        this.context = context;

        this.web = web;
        this.imageId = imageId;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return web.length;
    }



    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();



        View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_drawer_row, null, true);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);





        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        txtTitle.setText(web[position]);

        imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

}

and this my string values

```
<string-array name="nav_drawer_labels">
    <item>@string/title_home</item>
    <item>@string/title_videos</item>
    <item>@string/title_coupens</item>
    <item>@string/title_offers</item>
    <item>@string/title_extraearning</item>
    <item>@string/title_usemoney</item>
    <item>@string/title_ranking</item>
    <item>@string/title_faq</item>
    <item>@string/title_signout</item>
</string-array>
```

when i run it its give me one item only in ListView

and this my ListView xml

```
 <ListView
  android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
   android:id="@+id/list"

   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@color/dividercolour">

     </ListView>
```

[image]

I want to create a custom adapter for my list view.  so when i run the activity its show only one item

Comment: did you check you `web String[]` using `debbugger`? whether its has `length` more than `1`?

Comment: i do this
String[] web = {"aaaaaa","aaaaaa","aaaaaa","aaaaaa","aaaaaa","aaaaaa","aaaaaa","aaaaaa","aaaaaa"};
and same only one item append to listview

Comment: Change your `ListView`'s `layout_height` to `match_parent`.

Comment: Did you try to swap `adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();` and `list.setAdapter(adapter1);` ?

Comment: yes i actually add it when see it append one item only @NSimon

Comment: @MikeM. same one item only can u take look to my customAdapter code mabye its make the problem

Comment: I meant call `setAdapter` *first*, `notifyDataSetChanged` *after*

Comment: @NSimon i try it now same one item only

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `getCount()` and `getItemId()` methods

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] web;
    private final Integer[] imageId;
    public CustomList(Activity context,
                      String[] web, Integer[] imageId) {
        super(context, R.layout.nav_drawer_row, web);
        this.context = context;
        this.web = web;
        this.imageId = imageId;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_drawer_row, parent, false);
        Log.d("position",""+position);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);

        txtTitle.setText(web[position]);

        imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
        return rowView;
    }
}
}
```

Check the Log for position,whether it's displaying one item or all?

Comment: same one item only append :/

Comment: are you using listview inside a scrollview? and did you check the log?

Comment: D/position﹕ 0  D/position﹕ 1  D/position﹕ 0  D/position﹕ 0  D/position﹕ 0  D/position﹕ 0

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're assigning your arrays in the ArrayAdapter constructor incorrectly.

Instead of:

```
this.web = web;
this.imageId = imageId;
```

try:

```
this.web = Arrays.copyOf(web, web.length);
this.imageId = Arrays.copyOf(imageId, imageId.length);
```